# How to sort dictionary value of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is basically the same question at:

[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

However instead my dictionary value is a tuple with four floats.  How do I key off of an element in the nested tuple?

```
sorted_dict = {k: dict_cleanwhite[k] for k in 
    sorted(dict_cleanwhite.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)}
```

Output is:

```
KeyError: ('43 \n', (776.52, 466.3, 785.37504, 477.34))
```

How do I select the nested tuple element 776?

Started writing a function to return the tuple element:

```
def get_item(op_obj):
    for v in op_obj:
        return v
```

The problem is that the type `operator.itemgetter` returned is not identified, guessing to read documentation.

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Looks like you have some data quality issues. Can you post an excerpt of `dict_cleanwhite` which reproduces your error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems first you shouldn't convert it back to regular `dict`, it will lose it's sorting. Use `OrderedDict` to preserve order

And to sort by first item in tuple use `lambda` function `lambda i: i[1][0]`

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dict_cleanwhite.items(), key=lambda i: i[1][0], reverse=True))
```

Comment: This is great!  It works.  Also, I found that OrderedDict does a sort as well because I had to flag reverse=False to sort ascending.